# How to add images in semantic media wiki

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I need some images to display on my main page in (semantic media wiki)

Answer (score 2):

Semantic MediaWiki is just an extension that enables you to tag articles with properties and values understandable by computers, so you can query them later. It doesn't affect the other functionality of your MediaWiki, so you can upload files and insert them into your articles normally.

Please check this article to learn more about images and MediaWiki: [http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Images](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aImages)